# Is it possible to find the Rössler attractor using only a set of Lyapunov exponents?

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to use a set of Lyapunov exponents to determine the orbits of the Rössler system? If so, could how would I go about plotting them?

EG.

Known [image]

Unknown [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92743/discussion-on-question-by-grant-austin-peace-is-it-possible-to-find-the-rossler).

Comment: @Kuba Those comments should not have been moved in my opinion. Even if the question doesn't get an answer, those comments will still be useful for somebody else with the same question. Those comments are also a necessary read for anyone who wants to answer the question since those comments clarify the question beyond what is in the question itself.

Comment: @C.E. I understand but question must not need comments to be clear, if they are crucial they should be summed up in the question.

Comment: So what were the comments?  The chat no longer exists.